# Batch file: replace variable value in function

Tags: batch-file, replace, command-prompt

I have a variable set to a value.  I want to escape multiple characters in the string with a backtick (`).  Here is an example of replacing occurences of a parenthesis with a backtick:

```
@echo off

REM SET EXAMPLE VALUE
set EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files(x86)"
echo %EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR%

REM REMOVE QUOTES
set EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR=%EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR:"=%
echo %EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR%

REM REPLACE ( WITH `(
set EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR=%EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR:(=`(%
echo %EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR%
```

I'd prefer to have one function to replace all specified characters (*[]+ etc).  But I'm struggling.  From an example found here: http://www.dostips.com/DtTutoFunctions.php

I've tried this:

```
set EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files(x86)\Test"
echo %EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR%
call:myGetFunc EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR %EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR%
echo %EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR%

:myGetFunc
set "%~1=%%~2:(=`(%
goto:eof
```

But it doesn't work.  Any advice appreciated.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have two `%` signs next to each other, batch will interpret it as the type of variable used inside `for` loops (or as a literal %) and not do what you want. You can get around this by either using delayed expansion and placing the replace code inside of `!` or you can set the value to replace inside its own unique variable like this:

```
@echo off
set example_dir="C:\Program Files(x86)\test"
echo %example_dir%
call :addTick example_dir %example_dir%
echo %example_dir%
exit /b

:addTick
set return_var=%~2
set return_var=%return_var:(=`(%
set "%~1=%return_var%"
```

Comment: Thanks both for your responses.  This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Quite an old issue, but I have a question: So this is not possible to do with a single parameter? I mean not by calling method with two params and 'swapping' them.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
@echo off

set "EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files(x86)"
echo %EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR%

set "EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR=%EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR:(=`(%"
echo %EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR%

set "EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR=%EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR:)=`)%"
echo %EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR%

set "EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR=!EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR:%%=%%%%!"
echo %EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR%

endlocal
```

It is important to have the double quotes on right place. See answer on [specify redirect location using a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26459214/3074564) and [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) and others to understand the difference between

```
set var="value"
```

and

```
set "var=value"
```

I do not know why you want to insert a backtick as escape character in environment variable value as all the special characters listed at end of help output after entering `cmd /?` in a command prompt are interpreted literarily if the string containing the special characters is enclosed in double quotes.

And command `set` does not support regular expression replaces. Therefore several replaces are necessary to escape all special characters with a backtick.

The last one escaping a percent sign with one more percent sign is a little bit tricky. It requires delayed environment variable expansion and specifying 2 percent signs in batch file for each percent sign in string.

BTW: There is environment variable **ProgramFiles(x86)** containing the path to the default program files directory for 32-bit applications on 65-bit Windows computers.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files(x86)\Test"
echo %EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR%
call:myGetFunc EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR %EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR%
echo %EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR%
GOTO :EOF

:myGetFunc
set "%~1=%~2"
CALL set "%~1=%%%~1:(=`(%%"
GOTO :EOF
```

Note that this uses the target variable as a temporary variable for manipulation

Note also the extra "goto :eof" before the subroutine - otherwise batch will simply continue into the subroutine...

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files(x86)\Test"
echo %EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR%
call:myGetFunc EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR %EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR%
echo %EXAMPLEINSTALLDIR%
GOTO :EOF

:myGetFunc
set "%~1=%~2"
CALL set "%~1="%%%~1:(=`(%%""
GOTO :EOF
```

This version to restore the `"quotes"`

Note that there are limitations to this technique caused by the special meanings of some characters to batch.